# bit twiddling to right pack bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, simd, swar

I have the following code which right packs every 4 bits of a 64 bit int. This is the naive way of doing it, I am using a lookup table and a loop. I am wondering if there is a faster bit twiddling, swar/simd, parallel way to do this  any faster?  (msb() returns most significant bit)

```
def pack(X):

    compact = [
    0b0000,   # 0
    0b0001,  #  1
    0b0001,  # 10
    0b0011,  # 11
    0b0001,  #100
    0b0011,  #101
    0b0011,  #110
    0b0111,  #111
    0b0001, #1000
    0b0011, #1001
    0b0011, #1010
    0b0111, #1011
    0b0011, #1100
    0b0111, #1101
    0b0111, #1110
    0b1111, #1111
    ]

    K = 0
    while X:
        i = msb(X)
        j = (i//4 )*4
        a = (X & (0b1111 << j))>>j
        K |= compact[a] << j
        X = X & ~(0b1111 << j)
    return K
```

Comment: With what architecture / instruction set?

Comment: Most ISAs have a SIMD byte shuffle you can use as 16x 4-bit lookups in parallel.  (e.g. x86 `pshufb`).  Then it's just a matter of splitting bytes to nibbles and recombining.  (SIMD shift / `punpcklbw` / AND).  But your `msb(X)` seems to be a data dependency on which bits to grab, not just 16 independent operations within 4-bit groups?  Can you show a couple examples of 8 or 12-bit inputs and desired outputs, so it's easier to follow and grok your pseudo-code?

Comment: I use msb() because the bits are sparse, so I don't need to go over every single 16x4 bit group. There will in practice usually  be less than 7 bits sets  out of 64. There's no other reason to use msb(). if I can do all 16 in parallel then it is redundant.

this is actual working python code.

Comment: @VicC: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  If this is pure vertical SIMD within 4-bit groups, then yeah should be fairly straightforward with x86 SSSE3 `pshufb` or ARM NEON `vtbl`.  Maybe some micro-optimization in whether you unpack for one `pshufb` and then have to recombine, or just do two separate `pshufb` and then shift/OR back together.  Probably the latter.  I'm talking about assembly language, but of course you'll want to use intrinsics in some higher-level language to get a compiler to emit this asm.

Comment: If you building that for PCs, use what Peter wrote in the answer. If you build for ARM, it has `vcntq_u8` instruction which counts set bits in every byte; call it twice masking lower 4 bits / upper 4 bits of each byte with `vandq_u8` / `vbicq_u8` instructions.

Answer (score 4):

Most SIMD ISAs have a byte shuffle that can be used to implement a 16-entry LUT with 4-bit indices.  e.g. x86 SSSE3 `pshufb` or ARM/AArch64 `vtbl`/`tbl`.

Apparently `msb()` is just an optimization to skip all-zero nibbles, not a real data dependency, and this is pure vertical SIMD across nibbles.

So it's just a matter of splitting up into 4-bit nibbles and packing back again.  For x86, probably an odd/even split and doing the nibble LUT twice is better than packing them together (e.g. `punpcklbw` or `movlhps`)

```
; asm pseudocode; translate into intrinsics in a language of your choice

; constants:
    XMM7 = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0f)
    XMM6 = LUT
; input in XMM0, perhaps from  vmovq xmm0, rdi  or a load

    vpsrld xmm1, xmm0, 4          ; v >> 4
    vpand  xmm0, xmm0,  XMM7      ; v &= 0x0f
    vpand  xmm1, xmm1,  XMM7
    vpshufb xmm0, XMM6, xmm0      ; low nibbles
    vpshufb xmm1, XMM6, xmm1      ; high nibbles
    vpslld xmm1, xmm1, 4          ; high << 4   ; alternative: make a shifted copy of the LUT to avoid this
    vpor   xmm0, xmm0, xmm1

 ; result in low qword of XMM0; in C you might want  _mm_cvtsi128_si64
  ;  vmovq  rax, xmm0     get it back into an integer registers if necessary
```

This can actually do two 64-bit integers in parallel, in the high and low halves of XMM0, if you're doing this in a loop.

With AVX-512 VBMI for `vpermb`, you don't need to AND away the high bit before LUT lookups.  (`vpshufb` uses the high bit of the index to conditionally zero that element in the output, meaning you need it to be zero in most cases of using it as a LUT.)

Doing only one `vpshufb` could involve `vpunpcklbw` to duplicate each byte, possibly allowing re-combining with `vpmaddubsw` with a constant like `set1_epi16(0x1001)` to shift-and-add pairs of bytes, before `vpackuswb`.  Or perhaps a broadcast load to duplicate the whole 64-bit input, then AVX2 `vpsrlvq` to only right-shift the high half.  Then AND/vpshufb once each instead of twice.  Then vpunpckhqdq + vpslld + vpor to get the high half back down and combine.  So neither of these seem great.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that does not need any special SIMD instruction is to take each of the 4 bits into account separately:

```
def pack(x):
    r = x & 0x11111111
    r |= r + ((x >> 1) & 0x11111111)
    r |= r + ((x >> 2) & 0x11111111)
    r |= r + ((x >> 3) & 0x11111111)
    return r
```

Comment: Neat idea!  `r = r + ...` would just count the set bits in each nibble, but `r |= r + ...` gets carry-out to set the next highest bit, then ORs in the low bits again, appending.  (Or counting in unary).  If you're doing it for multiple integers, it vectorizes easily to right-pack nibbles over 128, 256, or 512 bits at a time.  (With 13 operations and one constant.)  So it's more efficient over a large array than my answer.